# Find document with highest calculated value in mongodb using c# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a way to find the document which have the highest calculated value in mongo db?

I have an array property which consists of int's 1-5. I want to find the document with the highest mean value.

Something like this using regular Linq:

```
var entityWithCalculatedMax = collection.OrderByDescending(x => x.Grade.Sum() / x.Grade.Count()).First();
```

Any suggestions?

(I am trying to do this directly in the database since I do not want to retrieve all documents to get the document)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be done using the LINQ syntax. It's easier (and more specific) to use the canonic aggregation syntax as it is documented in [the official "Aggregation Pipeline" documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

Example Input:

```
{ _id: 1, Grades: [ 1, 1 ] }
{ _id: 2, Grades: [ 2, 3, 4 ] }
{ _id: 3, Grades: [ 5 ] }
```

The idea is to have four steps in the aggregation pipeline:

1. **Unwind** each `Grades` array: For each document, this will create *n* documents where *n* is the number of grades with each document having a single grade:

   Result:

   ```
   { _id: 1, Grades: 1 }
   { _id: 1, Grades: 1 }
   { _id: 2, Grades: 2 }
   { _id: 2, Grades: 3 }
   { _id: 2, Grades: 4 }
   { _id: 3, Grades: 5 }
   ```
2. **Group** the documents by ID, aggregating the grades in a) an average property (your calculation) and b) a new Grades property to restore our array:

   Result:

   ```
   { _id: 1, Average: 1.0, Grades: [ 1, 1 ] }
   { _id: 2, Average: 3.0, Grades: [ 2, 3, 4 ] }
   { _id: 3, Average: 5.0, Grades: [ 5 ] }
   ```
3. **Sort** the documents by Average.

   Result: same as above, as it was already ordered somehow.
4. **Limit** to 1 document, as you only need the first result.

We can translate that to JSON and execute it against our db:

```
db.gradeDocs.aggregate(
    [
        { $unwind: "$Grades" },
        { 
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                Average: { $avg: "$Grades" },
                Grades: { $push: "$Grades" }
            }
        },
        { $sort: { "Average": 1 } },
        { $limit: 1 }
    ]
)
```

Ok, now how can we do this using the C# driver? The syntax is a little more verbose, but essentially it's the same thing:

```
var aggregateArgs = new AggregateArgs();
aggregateArgs.Pipeline =
    new[]
    {
        new BsonDocument("$unwind", "$Grades"), 
        new BsonDocument("$group", 
            new BsonDocument
            {
                {"_id", "$_id"},
                {"Average", new BsonDocument("$avg", "$Grades")},
                {"Grades", new BsonDocument("$push", "$Grades")},
            }),
        new BsonDocument("$sort", new BsonDocument("Average", 1)), 
        new BsonDocument("$limit", 1), 
    };

var resultId = collection
    .Aggregate(aggregateArgs)
    .Single()["_id"]
    .AsObjectId;
```